# Output looks different rendering in different resolutions

Tags: rendering, materials

I expected my rendering to look completely the same no matter what resolution. But the noise and/or reflection is way different when rendered 4x bigger for example. I resized the rendering to show the issue and put it next to the original output. Is there something wrong in the material?

Blend-file attached.

[image: rendering]

[image: material]

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is a good one :). After some tests, I think this could be caused by resampling (since there's a big difference in resolutions). Perhaps [Robert Gützkow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/74827/robert-g%c3%bctzkow) would know if that's even possible.